# My dad was rejected for a US Diversity Visa on 2003. Now I'm applying for a PHD, should I count my dad's rejection as mine in the DS-160 form?

Tags: visas, usa

On 2003, my father won DV lottery and our family was selected as a beneficiary. Now I’m applying for a PHD and I’m confused regarding the DS-160 form question about whether I was ever rejected. As I was a minor in 2003 (13 years) and also not the direct applicant, do I say yes to this question?

Comment: As you never applied, I would think the answer is no.  But you could just email or call and ask to be sure.

Comment: In the question title you father was _rejected_; in the question we _won_ the lottery. Which of those is the case?

Comment: There isn't an option in the DS 160 where it asks if any of your relatives was refused a visa, so you can say no.

Comment: @HenningMakholm It sounds like won the diversity visa lottery, rejected for the actual visa. People win a slot, only to get rejected (often for inability to support yourself, but for all the other usual reasons too). In short, the DV lottery system is actually pretty weird.